# Microsoft Excel duplicate formula in column

Tags: sql, microsoft-excel

I have this formula in an excel column and want to duplicate it in all the rows after the current row.

```
="INSERT INTO MyTable (ISAM_ID, ENTITY, CUSTOMER_MEDIA,STATUS,IIN,OID,FVC) VALUES (" & A2 & ", " & B2 & ", " & C2 & ", " & D2 & "," & E2 & ", " & F2 & ", " & G2 & ", " & H2 & ")"
```

How is this done in Excel?

Comment: could you please elaborate ? you can copy via drag and drop (left-click on the square on the bottom-right and drag the cell to the others you want to copy to)

Comment: @Farou Alhassan: It is considered polite to accept answers to your questions. To a large extent, you have neglected to do so. You may want to go back and accept answers to your previous questions. This may motivate further help from other StackOverflow users.

Comment: Oh, once again, the great xls2sql to the rescue!

Answer (score 0):

As @Jamx states, Copying the field down into subsequent fields works.

Doing this kind of sql construction you have to be careful that you don't break the sql statements you are trying to construct or include characters that are special to the sql environment you use to load the data (sqlplus for oracle has a define character usually &)

Note: You have a problem in the sql you are constructing, in that you need to enclose the strings you are trying to construct and probably add a sql termination character like ;.

i.e.
The formula should be:

```
="INSERT INTO MyTable (ISAM_ID, ENTITY, CUSTOMER_MEDIA,STATUS,IIN,OID,FVC)"
  & " VALUES (" & A2 & ", '" & B2 & "', '" & C2 
  & "', '" & D2 & "','" & E2 & "', '" & F2 & "', '" & G2 & "', '" & H2 & "');"
```

The sql output should be:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (ISAM_ID, ENTITY, CUSTOMER_MEDIA,STATUS,IIN,OID,FVC)
   VALUES ( 10001, 'ErferrRR01','MP3','LOADED'
   ,'RRGEE', '232133122dfcsdds212121','TGEE');
```

Comment: Additionally translating the special characters to encoded characters such as translate(string,"'","''")

Answer (score 0):

Click on the little square on the bottom right (called the fill handler) and drag/drop to the desired columns:

[image]